# How to Connect Two Networks of two different wireless routers with their own ISPs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ip

The first router is a TP-LINK WR740N v5:

- Has a Direct WAN Cable connected to it.
- The service is reliable, but slow (1 Mbps)
- IP Address of LAN is 192.168.0.1
- Hands out IP addresses from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.102
- Subnet Mask of 255.255.255.0

The second router is a iBall W3GX150N:

- Has a 4G USB Modem connected to it.
- The service is not stable, but very fast(25 Mbps)
- IP Address of LAN is 192.168.0.105
- Hands out IP addresses from 192.168.0.106 to 192.168.0.206
- Subnet Mask of 255.255.255.0

Now there is a TV and BD Player and XBOX One Connected to the iBall. For some reason I can't hard wire the routers. But I want to connect the two networks. So I have done WDS bridging between them, which works fine. Now whenever I connect to the TP-Link, I see that it tries to obtain an IP address from the iBall. Thus the device can't connect to the Internet via the TP-Link and vice versa.

Is there any way to keep both the DHCP Servers running and the wireless clients of TP-Link obtains an IP address from TP-Link DHCP ONLY, and vice versa? The 4G will connect via 4G and Tp-Link through Broadband.

Any help in the matter is requested from you my Friends.

Note:

- The BD, TV and XBOX is hard wired.
- It is important for the two ISPs to be available all the time via the specified routers. They have Static IPs.
- It is important to connect the two networks.
- Both have different SSIDs

Thanks, from Darknet99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to mainly use the fast 4G connection and use the slow 1Mbit connection as failover.

What you should do is switch off one of your DHCP-Servers and change the iBall's IP-Address to 192.168.0.2/24 to get a continous IP-Pool. Then configure the other DHCP server:

```
IP-Pool: 192.168.0.10-192.168.0.250
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 (/24)
Primary Gateway: 192.168.0.2
Secondary Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Primary DNS: 192.168.0.2
Secondary DNS: 192.168.0.1
```

If you want to keep the second DHCP-Server running (failover?) you have to adjust the pools like you did before (e.g. 10-130, 131-250). 
Don't worry about wifi clients, they will receive their ip configuration through both routers.

**^** Hope this solves your problem ;)

Comment: THANK YOU MY BUDDY It helped me.  But I dont want any of these as a failover; my iball supports dual wan.

Comment: I cant see any option of secondary gateway in my router admin interface